# Code completion for external JS library in Netbeans

Tags: javascript, netbeans, code-completion

I am current making some small JS game in Netbeans and I have started up a PHP project, which seems like the only viable option for a JS project.
I am using an external JS library which is not placed in the same library as my game.

I am not getting any code completion or referencing to this code.
I have tried to include it in the PHP include path, but that does not seems to work.

How can I get back my precious code completion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

copy the js file to your website root and use it with

```
<script src=""/>
```

or

```
<link href=""/>
```

and it will work. You can link it to an external source after project is over. Also, using external js files are not recommended. Make sure you are donwloading the development version or the documented development version of the JS file.

Comment: I have a js file referencing another js library and can't get intellisense.